# Getting [TOTAL DURATION ESTIMATE] and [TOTAL REMAINING DURATION] information using version one rest api

Tags: agile, versionone

[image]

How can i get these story total duration and remaining 
    duration using version one api?
Tried https://host/meta.v1/Story?xsl=api.xsl and https://host/meta.v1/Timebox?xsl=api.xsl API docs, but still not getting.

Answer (score 0):

The values that you are looking for are listed in meta as "Estimate" and "ToDo". To see those values for a specific story use something like this:

```
http://host/instance/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/5296?sel=Estimate,ToDo
```

To see a summation of all those values within a specific project (scope), use something like this:

```
http://host/instance/rest-1.v1/Data/Scope/5258?sel=Workitems:Story.Estimate.@Sum,Workitems:Story.ToDo.@Sum
```

Note that in that example, downcasting from Workitems to Stories is being used.